# Django authentication always fail and return None

Tags: django

I'm using Django to implement registration and login, but meet with some problems here.

My environment are Python3.7.2, Django 2.1.5 and Sqlite3. And I'm testing on localhost(127.0.0.1:8000).

I tried to create a user with the default function`User.objects.create_user()` , crucial codes are as follows, where userRegID, userRegPassword and userRegEmail are the data got from the frontend:

```
    user = User.objects.create_user(username = userRegID, password = userRegPassword, email = userRegEmail)
    user.first_name = userRegFirstName
    user.last_name = userRegLastName
    user.is_active = False
    user.is_staff = False
    user.is_superuser = False
    user.save()
```

And I set the user.is_active as true elsewhere(as I tried to use email validation)

The first problem is that the user data created can not be found in the table auth_user in sqlite but I can see it if I login as superuser on admin site.

Another problem is that after registration I tried to login, auth.authenticate function always return None. I've confirmed that the user is active on admin site. And I'm sure that the password is correct using check_password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set the authentication settings backend in your settings.py file as:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Comment: It works. I'm new to Django and I can see this is a careless mistake. Thanks a lot for your answer.